# mysql/percona: Unable to set password for the Percona Server "root" user- ppc64el

Tags: juju, openstack, ppc64le

**Enviroment**

I work for IBM and trying to prototype netboot (pxe) for ubuntu. This question is used to identify an issue that was encountered when using juju to deploy the 
https://jujucharms.com/u/openstack-charmers-next/openstack-base/40 bundle.
The bundle deploys out all necessary services (openstack, rabbitmq, ceph, mysql (percona) and so on.  Unfortunately the openstack 40 bundle out of the box fails
during mysql/percona deployment.

**Problem**

When setting up percona for mysql it fails due to

Unable to set password for the Percona Server "root" user

The above message is seen in the log for mysql on the node/machine that is 
running the lxc container for mysql/percona.

If you use juju status will see this:

```
mysql:
charm: cs:~openstack-charmers-next/trusty/percona-cluster-7
exposed: false
service-status:
  current: error
  message: 'hook failed: "install"'   <=====================
  since: 14 Oct 2015 16:19:51Z
relations:
  cluster:
  - mysql
units:
  mysql/0:
    workload-status:
      current: error
      message: 'hook failed: "install"'  <=====================
      since: 14 Oct 2015 16:19:51Z
    agent-status:
      current: idle
      since: 14 Oct 2015 16:19:51Z
      version: 1.24.6
    agent-state: error
    agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "install"'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Resolution**

This shows example of how to fix it using a standalone bundle only for mysql (percona).
Basically one has to allow openstack40 bundle to go to the point of mysql charm
failure and then you have to fix up things.  Below is the excercise we went through to make only mysql(percona) charm to work after it hit issue. Just change percona.yaml to openstack yaml you use.  Note that for ppc64le you have
to get the openstack 40 yaml and update it to arch=ppc64el since the charm store
openstack 40 bundle is only x86 relevant.

1. Deploy mysql / percona

   ```
    juju-deployer -c /root/.juju/bundles/percona.yaml -s 90 -d -v
   ```
2. Hit the mysql password issue. The problem that is listed above.
3. Set password in mysql container

   ```
   chroot /var/lib/lxc/juju-machine-0-lxc-1/rootfs/

    passwd root
   ```

   ---> for POC password: xxxxxxxx

   ```
    exit
   ```

   Note we list lxc machine juju-machine-0-lxc-1in example.  It has to
   be the lxc that mysql is deploying to.
4. Login to container

   ```
   lxc-console -n juju-machine-0-lxc-1
   ```
5. Fix problem

   ```
   UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('PASSW0RD') WHERE User='root';

   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

   exit
   ```

   https://serverfault.com/questions/502840/percona-mysql-unable-to-start-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file
6. Tell juju fixed charm

   ```
   juju resolved mysql/0 --retry  --show-log --debug
   ```
7. Redrive, shows previous steps are deployed and continues from failed charm.

   ```
   juju-deployer -c /root/.juju/bundles/percona.yaml -s 90 -d -v
   ```